# How to catch errors raised in Azure Device SDK?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I am using the [Azure Device SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp) for .NET Core in order to connect my devices to Azure IoT Hub. From time to time the server rejects some messages (like twin updates or telemetry messages) from the devices and responds with status code 400. As a result there are exceptions thrown on client side but due to its asynchronous nature they are swallowed somewhere inside the Azure SDK and never thrown at my code.

How can I actually be notified about these errors so I can handle and display them?

I can also see from the Azure Device SDK code that it uses some kind of logging (EventSource) but this is never enabled in the code:

```
From Logging.Common.cs:
Log.IsEnabled() // always returns false
```

Can you point me to some way where I can 1) actually enable logging in the Azure Device SDK and 2) find the content that was actually logged?

**Update:** Details regarding exception that is swallowed somewhere

```
// Fired here after I send twin reported properties to server:
AmqpTransportHandler.VerifyResponseMessage:
if (status >= 400)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Service rejected the message with status: " + status);
}

// Then becomes caught and re-fired here:                   
AmqpTransportHandler.SendTwinPatchAsync:                    
       throw AmqpClientHelper.ToIotHubClientContract(exception);

// Then it disappears somewhere in the "dance" of the async tasks
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture traces: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/master/tools/CaptureLogs

Our sample demonstrates best practice regarding exception catching, for example: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/blob/master/iothub/device/samples/DeviceClientMqttSample/Program.cs

Comment: Thanks for pointing me at the logging docs. I managed to create the logs using logman as described there and view them using PerfView as described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vancem/2012/07/09/introduction-tutorial-logging-etw-events-in-c-system-diagnostics-tracing-eventsource/). The exception mentioned above is also included in the logs which solves my inquiry.